# Newton's $\sin(r)/\sin(i)=n$

Tags: optics, refraction

$$\frac{\sin(r)}{\sin(i)}=n$$

In which works and how did Newton get it? Hence inverting the value. $n$ is the refractive index of water, thus light speed increased in water according to this.

It's wrong but I want to know how Newton got sines and not cosines or tangents there.

Comment: How Newton got it is a question for hsm.se. If you want an arbitrary proof, it can be derived from e.g. Fermat's principle. ([This](https://youtu.be/Iq1a_KJTWJ8) way is fun.)

Comment: @J.G. can u then shift it ti hsm.se, also if there is a space in the name how can I refer using @

Comment: i saw the springs example earlier but insight into newton would be great.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think only a moderator can move this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on a site dedicated to history of science.

Comment: There's historical info on Snell's law here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snell%27s_law#History Newton is not mentioned there...

Comment: There's an upvoted answer here which would be off-topic over at [hsm.se], so I'm reluctant to migrate this question. You can ask a version of it over there yourself. It's polite to be up-front if you cross-post similar questions on different sites, by editing each question to include a link to its counterpart.

Comment: @Minikute the way it is stated, it is certainly probable that at newton's time, refractive index was the ratio of speed of light in material to the speed of light in air and not the other way round. He would have derived it using Fermat's Principle only, as stated in the answer below. Also, he solved the brachistochrone problem using Fermat's principle and light only, so it is not probable that he got it wrong.

Answer (score 3):

As requested, here is a very common derivation to the formula above, aka Snell's law. The core idea behind this derivation is that light always takes the shortest path (Fermat's principle). Here is how it goes:
[image: Image of light refracting through two different media, the left denser than the right]

The time light takes is given by:

$$t=\frac{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}{v_1} +  \frac{\sqrt{b^2+(d-x)^2}}{v_2}.$$

This time must be minimised, so $\frac{dt}{dx}=0$.

Differentiating the above equation gives us
$$\frac{dt}{dx}=0\longrightarrow\frac{x}{v_1\sqrt{a^2+x^2}} -  \frac{d-x}{v_2\sqrt{b^2+(d-x)^2}}=0;$$

$$\frac{x}{v_1\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}=  \frac{d-x}{v_2\sqrt{b^2+(d-x)^2}}.$$

Also,

$$\sin(i)= \frac{x}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}\;\mathrm{and}\; \sin(r) = \frac{d-x}{\sqrt{b^2+(d-x)^2}}.$$

Thus, $$\frac{\sin(i)}{v_1}=\frac{\sin(r)}{v_2}.$$
Voila! Snell's Law.

Comment: The question does not ask for a derivation. It asks for the historical works where it first appeared.

Comment: @Brick Ig he was asking me "how Newton got sines and not cosines or tangents there" So essentially a derivation

Comment: "In which works and how did Newton get it?"

Comment: Ok if he asks that i am not sure, as i am only familiar with the physics of it. But the comments on his question indicated that he needed a derivation.

Comment: See the comment on the question by the moderator. Your answer is blocking this question from being migrated to a history-oriented site.